# SOQL: Filter on relationship field

Tags: soql

I have a visualforce page passing a value to controller.

Variable name is stFilter

My soql is:

```
Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,
                    (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                     FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                    (Select Name 
                     FROM Licenses__r)
                    FROM BCS__c
                    WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE
```

How do I filter it so that only BCS_c records that have a Licenses__r record with   "Name" value matching stFilter are returned.

Example
stfilter = Kansas

I only want to get back BCS__c records that have a Licenses__r record for Kansas.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, figured I would share.

```
Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,
                    (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                     FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                    (Select Name 
                     FROM Licenses__r
                    )
                    FROM BCS__c
                    WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE AND 
                    id in (select Hub_Name__c from LIcense__c where Name = :stFilter)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with SOQL alone, assuming that `BCS__c` is the parent object, and `License__c` is the child object.

I think the best you'll be able to do is bind your `stFilter` variable in your child sub-query (and then loop over the results).

Doing that will return `BCS__c` records with any number of `License__c` records (including those with 0 `License__c` records). These would be easy to detect and ignore in a loop.

The code ends up looking something like this

```
List<BCS__c> finalResults = new List<BCS__c>();
for(BCS__c preliminaryResult :[
    Select 
        Id, Name, User__r.Name,
        (Select 
            Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
        FROM 
            Account_Counselors__r),
        (Select 
            Name 
        FROM 
            Licenses__r
        WHERE 
            Name = :stFilter
        )
    FROM 
        BCS__c
    WHERE 
        Inactive__C = FALSE]
    ){

        if(preliminaryResult.Licenses__r.size() != 0){
            // Records that enter this if block will have at least 1 related License__c record
            finalResults.add(preliminaryResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would return all the accounts, but also accounts with that contact name.

Comment: I don't think that has any bearing here (and it'd be `Account_Counselor__c` records, not standard `Account` records). If you read further in my proposed code, the `if` block in the for loop takes care of the secondary filtering.

Comment: my bad! didn't see that